# Java generic return sub collection of type from parameters

Tags: java, generics

T: a type
C: a sub type of Collection
R: the return of comination of T and C

Example:
T = StackOverflow.class
C = List.class
R = `List<StackOverflow>`

How to exprime that in method signature?

It should be written like this?

```
<T, <C extends Collection>, R extends C<T>> HttpResponse<R> 
process(Class<T> returnType, Class<C> parametrizedReturnType)
```

I know `C<T>` does not work.

In order to do

```
List<StackOverflow> res = process(StackOverflow.class, List.class)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is 'comination', what is 'exprime'?

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid the issues with raw types (etc) you can pass in something like a "prototype" object:

```
<T, C extends Collection<T>> HttpResponse<C> process(C prototype) {
  ...
}
```

So you can invoke this like:

```
HttpResponse<List<String>> response = process(new ArrayList<>());
```

The nature of the prototype object depends upon what you need to do with it in the `process` method. Perhaps you can accept an empty list; perhaps you would need to pass in a supplier of an instance, for example:

```
<T, C extends Collection<T>> HttpResponse<C> process(Supplier<C> supplier) {
  return new HttpResponse<>(supplier.get());
}

HttpResponse<List<String>> response = process(ArrayList::new);
```